# Ansible "rc" conditional check failed with the when condition

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

my playbook is failing while performing the conditional check based on the `register` value.= with the `when` condition.

Below Play is a part of ansible role:

### My Playbook

```
---
- name: CIS 5.4.4 Ensure default user umask is 027 or more restrictive (/etc/profile 1/2)
  shell: tail -1 /etc/profile | grep "umask 027"
  register: umask_grep
  changed_when: false
  failed_when: false

- name: CIS 5.4.4 Ensure default user umask is 027 or more restrictive (/etc/profile 2/2)
  shell: echo umask 027 >> /etc/profile
  when: umask_grep[ "rc" ] != 0
  become: yes

- name: CIS 5.4.4 Ensure default user umask is 027 or more restrictive (/etc/bashrc 1/2)
  shell: tail -1 /etc/bashrc | grep "umask 027"
  register: umask_grep
  changed_when: false
  failed_when: false

- name: CIS 5.4.4 Ensure default user umask is 027 or more restrictive (/etc/bashrc 2/2)
  shell: echo umask 027 >> /etc/bashrc
  when: umask_grep[ "rc" ] != 0
  become: yes
```

While i'm executing this its giving following error..

### Error:

```
fatal: [xx.xx.xx.xx]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The conditional check 'umask_grep[ \"rc\" ] != 0' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (umask_grep[ \"rc\" ] != 0): 'dict object' has no attribute 'rc'\n\nThe error appears to be in 'umask_is_027_or_more_restrictive.yml': line 8, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: CIS 5.4.4 Ensure default user umask is 027 or more restrictive (/etc/profile 2/2)\n  ^ here\n"
}
```

Even i tried changing the `when: umask_grep[ "rc" ] != 0` to `when: umask_grep.rc != 0` but even getting the same message.

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

### My Ansible version

ansible 2.9.10

### Debug info

```
skipping: [xx.xx.xx.xx] => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "tail -1 /etc/profile | grep \"umask 027\"",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "stdin_add_newline": true,
            "strip_empty_ends": true,
            "warn": true
        }
    },
    "msg": "skipped, running in check mode"
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce that error running the playbook in your question with Ansible 2.9.10. Can you update this question with a complete reproducer? Not just a list of tasks, but a playbook that, when run, generates the error about which you are asking.

Comment: @larsks, thanks for the comment, however this a a complete playbook in itself it's just that its a part of a role so, its complete one. I just updated the debug info if that helps.

Comment: You failed to mention in your question that you were running in check mode.

Comment: @larsks, sorry i just ran it into verbose mode and just recall it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running in check mode, Ansible will not execute `shell` or `command` tasks. Since the shell script in your "check for umask" tasks doesn't run, the corresponding result that you register in `umask_grep` does not have an `rc` attribute. That is the source of your error.

The simplest solution is probably to set a default value when the `rc` attribute isn't available:

```
- name: CIS 5.4.4 Ensure default user umask is 027 or more restrictive (/etc/profile 2/2)
  shell: echo umask 027 >> /etc/profile
  when: umask_grep.rc|default(0) != 0
  become: yes
```

You could also modify your playbook so that your `grep` tasks do run in check mode:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: CIS 5.4.4 Ensure default user umask is 027 or more restrictive (/etc/profile 1/2)
      check_mode: false
      shell: tail -1 /etc/profile | grep "umask 027"
      register: umask_grep
      changed_when: umask_grep.rc != 0
      failed_when: false

    - name: CIS 5.4.4 Ensure default user umask is 027 or more restrictive (/etc/profile 2/2)
      shell: echo umask 027 >> /etc/profile
      when: umask_grep is changed
      become: yes

    - name: CIS 5.4.4 Ensure default user umask is 027 or more restrictive (/etc/bashrc 1/2)
      check_mode: false
      shell: tail -1 /etc/bashrc | grep "umask 027"
      register: umask_grep
      changed_when: umask_grep.rc != 0
      failed_when: false

    - name: CIS 5.4.4 Ensure default user umask is 027 or more restrictive (/etc/bashrc 2/2)
      shell: echo umask 027 >> /etc/bashrc
      when: umask_grep is changed
      become: yes
```

In this model, the tasks that make changes don't need to explicitly check the `rc` attribute, since we're using that in the `grep` tasks to set the task's "changed" state.

Comment: Thank you so much @larsks .

Comment: This looks `umask_grep.rc|default(0) != 0` nice, Is there any diffrence using it as `when: umask_grep[ "rc" ] != 0` .

Comment: There is no diference between `somevar.key` and `somevar["key"]` other than some extra typing.

Comment: Thanks a lot again  , thanks for the answer, Stay safe stay healthy!